# How to port RelativeLayout from Android source code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

### Background

I have a card-like UI on [**my app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), which uses a RelativeLayout.

### The problem

Recently I've discovered that on at least one device ( or rom, or andorid version), when I switch to an RTL language (such as Hebrew), everything got messed up.

This has happened only on LG G2 with Android V4.2.2 .
Here's what I see:

[image]

If you compare it to the screenshots of the app, you can see this is not how it should look like.

That's even though on all Android devices that I've checked, and on all emulators, I've never seen it (even when switching to Hebrew).

### What I've tried

I've tried to fix it by using a [**GridLayout instead**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26619445), but that wasn't working well (link here).

I've also tried to use a LinearLayout, but considering there might be issues with it, I've used [**LinearLayoutCompat**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat.html) instead. It works, but it's not recommended to use so many.

Another thing I've tried is to port the RelativeLayout of Android source code, but this gives me a lot of warnings and errors that are quite hard to handle.

Here's the original XML of the layout, BTW (I've removed the irrelevant stuff, to make it shorter) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" > 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appIconImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appDetailsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/appIconImageView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/overflowView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appIconImageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/overflowView"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="label" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="description" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overflowView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/isSystemAppImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### The question

As I use RelativeLayout, how can I port the code from the official source code of Android?

Is there maybe a library that does it?

Comment: It is probably easier to work around the issue that to try and extract RelativeLayout from the framework. What are you expecting to see on this screen (I couldn't find a similar one in your app listing)?

Comment: I've put the link to the app, so you can see the screenshots of what should be shown. Here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . look at the first image (the one on the left), and ignore the upper part (of the multi-selection). I've already tried multiple attributes, and the weird thing is that it occurs on a very specific configuration: G2, Android 4.2.2, Hebrew . on all other devices and configurations, I didn't have this issue.

Comment: I've now also posted the XML layout I've originally used. Hope it will help.

Comment: What does LINT says about RTL layout support? It usually gives hints about possible RTL issues. Have you tried using `layoutDirection` attribute with `locale` value? layoutdirection was introduced in 4.2+

Comment: my suggestion is try using Linear layout as parent and add those relative layout inside it.. so that you dont face any problem in design

Comment: @Naufal That's what I've done now, but I was hoping for a better solution. I think I can notice the difference in speed. I've even used the compat-version of it, to make sure it will work the same across all devices. Thing is, this problem only occured on a very specific configuration.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I've actually went over all of Lint's warnings and added all that it has suggested. as I noticed "layoutDirection" is defaults to "locale" so that it will change the direction based on the locale. You can try it yourself by installing the app and change the locale. Here's how Hebrew is written: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/7093/y2vh.png (the third item). I'd give it 99% chance that it will still look ok, just change directions of stuff.

Comment: @android developer, Hello. I have a similar problem just with LG G2 RTL mode. RelativeLayout with ListView fill just a 1/3 of screen width, but LayoutParams are MathParrent. Have you fixed your bug?

Comment: @VladimirKulyk As I wrote, I have it on the exact same device (LG G2). I didn't really fix it. I just used a LinearLayout . In fact, to make sure it works well, I've used the one that's in the support library. You can try out my app and see that it works fine there, and also inspect the views by using DDMS's view hierarchy feature